# How can I find the minimum value correctly that enter by user?

Tags: c++

Most of the code seems to be okay need help with the part to find the minimum. What condition do I have to write in order to find the minimum number enter by user and exclude the zero as minimum number?

```
#include<iostream>//header
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n , sentinel = 0, max = 0, min, count = 0, sum = 0;
double avg;
cout << "Enter a series of number terminated by 0:" << endl;//prompt user to input a series of number

do {
    cin >> n;//read the input
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (n>max)
            max = n;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (n<min)
            min = n;
    }
    sum = sum + n;
    count++;



} while (n!= sentinel);
count--;
avg = sum / count;

cout << "You have enter " << count << " integers" << endl;//display how may input user enter
cout << "Average is " << avg << endl;//display average
cout << "Max is " << max << endl;//display maximum number
cout << "Min is " << min << endl;//display minimum number
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Wrong page. This should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You need a sensible starting value for `min`, but your code doesn't work for the maximum (try inputting only negative numbers) or average (try 1 and 2, or -1 and 2) either.

Comment: Try to explain to a friend (even an imaginary one) what the point of the `for (int i ...` loops is.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: this sounded like a code review, but in fact it is a request for someone to add additional functionality. It's too broad here (request for free work) but I doubt that "review this code" without much extra detail would be on-topic at Code Review anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the maximum possible value for your `int min;` and the minimum possible value for your `int max;`:

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Then *whatever* you enter for the `min` must be smaller than its initial value and whatever you enter for the `max` must be larger than its initial value.

Comment: It should be swapped, shouldn't it? Otherwise `if (n<min) min = n;` and `if (n>max) max = n;` will never be true.